# shinyapp deployment working locally but not in shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, cloud

I have a simple proof-of-concept shinyapp that I am trying to publish to shinyapps.io, and it is working fine locally in RStudio but when I try to deploy it the webpage can't load and it times out giving a "startup took too long" error.

I suspect that the issue comes from the fact that I am obtaining the data for analysis from Box through an API via the "boxr" package. In order to query Box a redirect URI is required, the only one of which I have created is for my local machine (the URL looks something like http://localhost:1352/), but I don't understand how these work or what other URI I need to save as an approved redirect for others to access the app online. My code is below, the global.R file just grabs and appends a couple data files from my Box account

Another issue is that the Box account is an Enterprise account through a university, so I don't have full permissions. Does anyone know how something like this would work? What steps do I need to take to make it so my shinyapp webpage has approval to source files from Box?

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(rsconnect)

source("global.R")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Owasco Met Data"),
  mainPanel(
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- renderDataTable(
    DT::datatable(df_df2,
                  options = list(pageLength = 15,
                                 lengthMenu = list(c(5,15,-1), c("5", "15", "All")),
                                 searching = TRUE,
                                 autowidth = TRUE)
                  )
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)`
```

And the global.R code:

```
key = "placeholder"
sec = "placeholder"

box_auth(client_id = key, client_secret = sec)

box_dl("1210799892985",
       local_dir = getwd(),
       overwrite = TRUE,
       file_name  = "metdata.csv")
box_dl("1210808988045",
       local_dir = getwd(),
       overwrite = TRUE,
       file_name = "winddata.csv")

df <- read.csv("metdata.csv")

df2 <- read.csv("winddata.csv")

unlink(c("metdata.csv", "winddata.csv"))

df <- df[-c(1:3), -c(7,8)]

df2 <- df2[-c(1:3), -c(1,2,5:9)]

df_df2 <- bind_cols(df, df2)

names(df_df2) <- c("Date.Time", "Record", "AirTemp_C", "RHumid", "P_mb", "SolarRad", "Wind Direction", "Wind Speed")
```

Comment: See the discussions at https://github.com/r-box/boxr/issues/165